# Using TTreeCache with TChain friends

Tags: root-framework

I'm using three TChains friended together in my analysis code, with addresses set only for some branches on each chain. What is the best way for me to use TTreeCache in this scenario? Do I have to manually specify which branches to cache? I want to cache all the branches, which have their addresses set, but only those.

On a separate note, I'd like to first only get entries from the first tree, and only in case I decide to further analyze the event get entries from the other friended trees.

Comment: What was unclear about the documentation of [`TTreeCache`](https://root.cern.ch/root/html/TTreeCache.html) (case 3 in the section *HOW TO USE the TreeCache*)?

Comment: What was unclear is whether this work for branches on friended trees.